# How to crop rows and columns of pixels out in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-manipulation, pixel, crop, tiff

I have an image with a white border around it, and I need to get rid of the border.  There are 20 rows of white pixels above the image, 5 columns of white to the left, 5 of white columns to the right, and 5 rows of white below the image.  I wan't to crop the image exactly out of that border, how do I do this in matlab?  Thanks for any help you can give!

(The image is a tiff, which is why I can't use an online service for this, they won't let me upload .tiff)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the built-in MATLAB function `imcrop`. To use it, specify something like

```
B = imcrop(A,[xmin ymin width height]);
```

if A is your original image. First find the dimensions of your image. Say its 800 by 600. Then you are looking to crop a 770 by 580 image so these numbers respectively will be your width and height in the above function. Your x and y would be something like 5 and 20, respectively.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.  the reulting image needs to be a 128x1500.  And when I did I = imread(pic); I got that I is a 153x1510x3 matrix.  What you're saying seems right, but I got a bunch of errors like "??? Error using ==> imcrop>checkCData at
381
Invalid input image."

Comment: ok I did B = imcrop(I,[5 20 128 1500]) and it returned B as a <134x129x3> matrix.

Comment: B = imcrop(I,[6 21 1500 128]) gets me a <129x1501x3> and I can't seem to get rid of that last row and column.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Yeah just subtract off that last pixel. I think this would mean `B = imcrop(I,[6 21 1499 127])`.

Answer (score 2):

U can use [imcrop](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/images/ref/imcrop.html) for this if you have image processing toolbox or you can make new image as follows:

```
I2 = I(21:end-5, 6:end-5)
```

For 3 dimensions, you can use:

```
I2 = I(21:end-5,6:end-5,:)
```

For example as per your comment:

```
I = rand(153,1510,3);
size(I); %  153        1510           3
I2 = I(21:end-5,6:end-5,:);
size(I2); % 128        1500           3
```

Comment: I tried this and just got an error.  I used the image processing toolbox but couldn't get precise enough (it kept leaving one white line of pixels at the bottom.  I did I = imread(pic) and I is now a <153x1510x3> matrix.  when you say "end-5" what end are you talking about? I need to turn that picture of 153x1510 pixels into one of 128x1500 pixels by cutting 20 rows off the top, 5 off the bottom, and 5 columns off each end.

Comment: If you use `imcrop`, you don't need to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
newIm = oldIm(20:length(oldIm(:,1))-5,5:length(oldIm(1,:))-5)
```

Comment: That returns newIm as a <129x4521> and the color scheme is super distorted.

Comment: Its because your is a colour image; user2613077 answer works well for grayscale ones. The same fix Marcin applied works for here too.